# Can't write raw data on SD card under Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, file, sd-card

I am trying to write raw data on my SD card under Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

I need this cause I want to write my own "filesystem" from which I can easily read under microcontroller (arm based).

I am able to read data from SD card, but when I try to write some it gives me an error of:

"`Operation not permitted`".

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open */
#include <unistd.h>     /* exit */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>      /* ioctl */
#include <errno.h>
#define DEVICE "/dev/sdb1" /* SD card */

int main()
{
   int file_desc, ret_val;
   char msg[512];
   msg[0] = 'H';
   char answer[512];
   file_desc = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR);
   if(file_desc < 0)
      printf("failed to open the device \n");

   ret_val = write(file_desc, msg, 512);
   fsync(file_desc);
   printf("%d\n", ret_val);
   printf("%d\n", errno);
   read(file_desc, answer, 512);

   printf("message read is %s\n", answer);
   close(file_desc);
   return 0;
}
```

As I said, I can open file in `read/write` mode and read data from it, but in these lines:

```
ret_val = write(file_desc, msg, 512);
fsync(file_desc);
printf("%d\n", ret_val);
printf("%d\n", errno);
```

I get `ret_val = -1` (which means error), and `errno = 1` (which means " Operation not permitted").

I would be very grateful for any advice that would help me write raw data on my SD card.

Comment: Are you running this program as root? Regular users usually don't have permission to access devices in `/dev/`.

Comment: Yes i run this program as: sudo ./a.out

Comment: Before you go any further, check to see if there's a write-protect switch on the side of the card/adaptor and make sure it is off (if it exists).

Comment: Of course it was :/. I spend almost two hours try to fix it :P. Thank you :)

Comment: You're probably already aware of `dd(1)`, but just in case: Instead of writing your own program, you could just do `dd if=fs_image of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to do this with dd(1) instead of direct write from C code? And if i use dd(1) there won't be any complications to read this data from uC?

Comment: @bercik may I ask, does the above code work after you write to the SD card using the ARM MCU? It worked for me before doing so and now if I want to read from the SD card (without formating) using a Linux machine, I have to use xxd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go any further, check to see if there's a write-protect switch on the side of the card/adaptor and make sure it is off (if it exists).